# Is there a way to access an object property before it is defined?

Tags: javascript, object

I know that this question sounds stupid, but i don't know how to make that possible what i want.

Here is my code:

```
function createPerson() {

  var x1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*101); // Random number picker

  var personObject = {
    primaryNation:  primNation(),
    secondaryNation: secNation(),
  };

  function createRandomNation() {               //Random nation picker

    var nations = ["Germany", "USA", "France"];
    var randomNation = nations[Math.floor(Math.random() * nations.length)];
    return randomNation;
  }



  function primNation(){

    var randomPrimaryNation = createRandomNation();
    return randomPrimaryNation;
  }


  function secNation() {

    var randomSecondaryNation = [];

    if (x1 >= "10") {
      randomSecondaryNation = createRandomNation();
      if (randomSecondaryNation === personObject.primNation){       //// <---There is the problem
        randomSecondaryNation = false;
      }
    }
    else {
      randomSecondaryNation = false;
    }

    return randomSecondaryNation;
  }
  console.log(personObject);
}
```

The problem is where I compare randomSecondaryNation === (the object, but it is not "finished" defined.

Is the only way to create seperate objects and assign them together or is there a smarter/faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make one call and return the object with primary and secondary?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't even make sense. You are comparing the randomly generated secondary nation against a secondaryNation that doesn't exist yet to see if it is the same. You are also comparing if `x1 >= "10"` when x1 is a Number and "10" is a String. Also, `randomSecondaryNation` starts out as an array, then becomes a string from the `createRandomNation()` return value, and then in the if/else condition, you set it to `false`. Why is that variable an array, string, and boolean? What exactly are you trying to do? Let's address the problem, not your attempted solution.

Comment: @epascarello but how can I call the function once and write in these two different properties?

Comment: @mhodges ups sorry, i meant to compare randomSecondaryNation with person.Object.primNation

Comment: `var personObject = yourFunctionThatReturnsBoth()` ?

Comment: @Andy Yeah, that's what I figured. The rest of the comment still stands, though. epascarello's solution is what you're looking for - implementing it shouldn't be too difficult. Just combine the code from your primNation and secNation functions into a single function, do your validation/checking, and return an object containing primary and secondary nation and assign it to your personObject

Comment: @mhodges alright, I will do that, thanks again!

Comment: @Andy See if my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can combine the two functions, although I am still uncertain as to why randomSecondaryNation starts out as an array, then gets assigned a string value, and then conditionally becomes a boolean. There may be a good reason for this, but in my experience, this is a bug waiting to happen. Anyway, here you go:

```js
function createPerson() {

  var x1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*101); // Random number picker
  
  function createRandomNation() {               //Random nation picker
    var nations = ["Germany", "USA", "France"];
    var randomNation = nations[Math.floor(Math.random() * nations.length)];
    return randomNation;
  }
  
  function generateNations () {
    var randomPrimaryNation = createRandomNation();
    var randomSecondaryNation = [];

    if (x1 >= "10") {
      randomSecondaryNation = createRandomNation();
      if (randomSecondaryNation === randomPrimaryNation){
        randomSecondaryNation = false;
      }
    }
    else {
      randomSecondaryNation = false;
    }

    return {
      primaryNation: randomPrimaryNation,
      secondaryNation: randomSecondaryNation
    };
  }
  
  var personObject = generateNations();
  console.log(personObject);
}

createPerson();
createPerson();
createPerson();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The bug as you metioned before is happening :D

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that? It happens just a few times

Comment: @Andy Well it happens every time `randomSecondaryNation` generates the same value as `randomPrimaryNation`. Fixing this issue all depends on what functionality is desired. Do you just want to reroll until you get a different nation for the secondary? Do you want to spit out an error message? What do you want to happen?